# Getting HTTP Post Value From Another Project

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core

I have two projects in one solution. I have to post something from the first project to the second project.

My post method in the first project:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("count")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Count(DateTime date)
    {
       
        var section = this._configuration.GetSection("product");
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            string countDate =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(date);
           
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(section.GetValue<string>("Host"));
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(section.GetValue<string>("Endpoint"), new StringContent(countDate));
            if(responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var operationResult =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultJSON>(content);
                int result = await _dataService.Counts(operationResult);
                return Ok(result);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to send date. When I debug the code the countDate in the line of `HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(section.GetValue<string>("Endpoint"), new StringContent(countDate));` is correct. When I continue to debug, it goes to second project.

My post method in the second project:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("count")]
  public ActionResult Count(string content)
    {
        DateTime date = (DateTime)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
        var serviceResult = this._countingService.Count(date);
        return Ok(serviceResult);
    }
```

In here, the content value comes null. How I get the content value that comes from first project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the StringContent like below:

```
new StringContent(countDate, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
```

And add [FromBody] to the second project post method:

```
public ActionResult Count([FromBody]string content)
```

Comment: Thx, I applied your solution and I got an error here `DateTime date = (DateTime)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);` about time conversion. I fix this like that `DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(content);`